# UITableview lost reference after pop view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

For example i have  `ViewController1` with `UITableview` object and data.Then i will push to another controller from `ViewController1` to `ViewController2` .

My problem is when i am trying to pop from `ViewController2` to `ViewController1` then `UITableview` object return `nil` and my application is crashed.This problem often happen.

I am using storyboard for assign `UITableview`. And I am using `swift 2.0` as programming language.

Below is my source code where my app is crashed.

```
  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    btnRightBarBtnItem.image = UIImage(named : "Home")
    btnRightBarBtnItem.target = self
    btnRightBarBtnItem.action = #selector(self.btnHomeAction)

    refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SelectPackingItemsViewController.refresh(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
     packingItemsTableView.addSubview(refreshControl)   
}
```

App is crashed on "packingItemsTableView.addSubview(refreshControl)" this line.

It returns in log 
(lldb) po self.packingItemsTableView!
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

refresh control is nothing but "UIRefreshControl() object" which does not nil.

Comment: Add your code work where app is crashed.

Comment: Share crash log or your source. Do have removed any view programatically during view life cycle events?

Comment: declare and initialise your `refreshControl` object in `viewDidAppear` and try running code again OR move all `viewDidAppear ` code to `viewDidLoad `

Answer (score 0):

check whether data for table view still exists after you pop 2nd controller, might be its not getting its datasource. keep strong reference for Array which contains tableview's data